# How to send a List object through a callback function in Flutter?

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart, callback

**What I've already done**

I have a stateful widget that generates a ListView on screen.

```
class AppListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged onChange;
  final List<MatchList> matchList;
  final ValueChanged finalBetList;

  AppListView({this.onChange, this.matchList, this.finalBetList});

  @override
  _AppListViewState createState() => _AppListViewState();
}

class _AppListViewState extends State<AppListView> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<MatchList> betList = List<MatchList>();
```

I have a Home Screen that calls this Stateful Widget. In here I am using a callback function (onChange) to get the counter value from the widget. Everything is working perfect.

```
Stack(children: [
          AppListView(
            matchList: matchList,
            //callback function brings the counter value from ListView class
            onChange: (value) {
              setState(() {
                counter = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 280.0, left: 330.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    counter > 0
                        ? Navigator.pushNamed(context, BetScreen.id)
                        : print('you shall not pass');
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    counter.toString(),
                    style: kTextStyleAppBarTitle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ])
```

**What is the problem**

But when I am trying to call that widget from another screen with a similar callback function(finalBetList), I got "The method 'call' was called on null. Receiver: null" error. Actually everything that I do is the same as the other example that works fine. I can't find what I'm missing. Is it something about Lists?

```
class _BetScreenState extends State<BetScreen> {
  List<MatchList> betList = List<MatchList>();
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        currentBalance: '\u0024' + '200.00',
        userLevel: 'Level 30',
        userName: 'Mark',
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: AppListView(
          finalBetList: (value) {
            setState(() {
              //counter = value;
              betList = value;
              //print(betList);
            });
          },
          matchList: betList,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After Edit

I added the cod of AppListView widget

```
 class AppListView extends StatefulWidget {
      final ValueChanged onChange;
      final List<MatchList> matchList;
      final ValueChanged finalBetList;

      AppListView({this.onChange, this.matchList, this.finalBetList});

      @override
      _AppListViewState createState() => _AppListViewState();
    }

    class _AppListViewState extends State<AppListView> {
      int counter = 0;
      List<int> betList = List<int>();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

                                children: <Widget>[
                                  AppButton.buildAppButton(
                                    context,
                                    AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
                                    widget.matchList[index].homeOdds,
                                    kCategoryButtonDimensions,
                                    color: widget.matchList[index].homeSelected
                                        ? Colors.yellow
                                        : Colors.white,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (widget.matchList[index].drawSelected ||
                                          widget.matchList[index].awaySelected) {
                                        widget.matchList[index].drawSelected =
                                            false;
                                        widget.matchList[index].awaySelected =
                                            false;
                                        counter--;

                                        //betList part
                                        if (betList.length > 0)
                                          betList
                                              .remove(widget.matchList[index].id);
                                      }
                                      widget.matchList[index].homeSelected =
                                          !widget.matchList[index].homeSelected;

                                      if (widget.matchList[index].homeSelected) {
                                        counter++;
                                        betList.add(widget.matchList[index].id);
                                      } else {
                                        counter--;
                                        if (betList.length > 0)
                                          betList.remove(widget.matchList[index]
                                              .id); //if selected, add to betList to send BetScreen
                                      }
                                      widget.onChange(counter);
                                      print(betList);
                                      widget.finalBetList(betList);

                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                  ),
```

Comment: i think you are not providing onChange function in second call and it is causing problem.  onChange: (value) { }, if you even don't want pass this function. may solve your issue.  i am not sure because i don't know your _AppListViewState implementation.

Comment: nope, it did not work. Still same issue, it says The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null Tried calling: call(Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList') . This is how I implemented these callback functions in _AppListViewState. widget.onChange(counter); widget.finalBetList(betList);. İsn't it about lists?

Comment: I think this is happening because list you are passing ( betList) in second screen which is null  in the beginning so this error is happening. In first screen list is also empty or not? Can you add full code of AppListView widget.

Comment: I added AppListView code (relevant part only). Please look at the onPressed function. At last, I print the betList and see that it is not null and true. But when I added the last row widget.finalBetList(betList); I still get the same error.